# How to implement show/hide sections in collectionview with swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell

I was searching the whole internet for that and i'm not sure if it can be done, cause i'm new in iOS development.I want when my app starts to show me only the first section of header and my cells. Then when i click in one of my cells, i want to show me from below the section 2 with header and my cells etc.I have set the cells and sections correctly, also i can choose each cell and change the background color correctly etc. My app runs but it shows me all the sections and cells at once.

For example:

App Starts and i must see the Section 1 only:

**Section 1 header**

**cell1** **cell2** **cell3**

Then i click in cell1 and i must see the Section 1 and 2 only:

**Section 1 header**

**cell1** **cell2** **cell3**

**Section 2 header**

**cell1** **cell2** **cell3** **cell4**

Then i click in cell4 and i must see the Section 1 and 2 and 3 only:

**Section 1 header**

**cell1** **cell2** **cell3**

**Section 2 header**

**cell1** **cell2** **cell3** **cell4**

**Section 3 header**

**cell1** **cell2**

etc.

I found that i have to use these methods mentioned below but i don't know how to implement the show/hide sections in my collection.

Here is my code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {cell!.contentView.layer.backgroundColor =  colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.4784313725, blue: 1, alpha: 1)}
        if (indexPath.row == 1) {cell!.contentView.layer.backgroundColor =  colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.4784313725, blue: 1, alpha: 1)}
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) { cell!.contentView.layer.backgroundColor =  colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)}
        if (indexPath.row == 1) { cell!.contentView.layer.backgroundColor =  colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)}
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you are modeling your data so that you can track which section should be hidden (and the cell background color). Maybe you already are but I'll just give an example:

```
class MyModelSection {
    var items = [MyModel]()
    var hidden = true
}

class MyModel {
    var backgroundColor: UIColor?
}

class MyViewController: UICollectionViewController: {
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    var dataSource = [MyModelSection]()
    var visibleDataSource: [MyModelSection] {
        return dataSource.filter { !$0.hidden }
    }

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 }
```

Then you can use the [`UICollectionViewDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource) protocol to determine the sections that should be displayed

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return visibleDataSource.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return visibleDataSource[section].items.count
}
```

Of the functions you listed I'd imagine that you would use:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Not sure how your logic for picking which one gets displayed...
    guard visibleDataSource.count >= indexPath.section else {
        return
    }

    let dataForNextSection = visibleDataSource[indexPath.section + 1]
    dataForNextSection.hidden = false
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```